# Can't take screenshots after updating to 14.10 from 14.04

Tags: 14.10, screenshot

(Sorry if this doesn't belong here)

I updated to 14.10 last night, and today I've been trying to take screenshots of various things but I'm not able to take it properly. Before, I wuold hit PrntScr and the screen would be captured normally. However, if I do it now, it takes a picture of something that was open in the past.

^That probably made no sense what-so-ever but the following images should explain what the problem is:

This is what I want to take a screenshot of (taken with my phone since PrntScr isn't working):
[image: Target]

But, when I press PrntScr, I get this (or something that's not what I want):
[image: Result]

I have tried with Screenshot programs like Shutter and Gyazo, and they both give me the same result.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling all of the screenshot programs, and then installing the one of your choice? If not would you mind giving that a try and then reboot, then try a Print-Screen again and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Actually, void that last comment of mine. It worked a few times, but now I'm still getting what I'm not supposed to get. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, after taking the first screenshot, every other screenshot is the same image even if the screen has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I managed to fix it.

The problem is with the Graphics Drivers that ship with Ubuntu 14.10. Upgrading to a newer driver fixed the problem.

This can be a little risky, but the easiest way I know of to do this is to install the oibaf (i.e. bleeding edge) drivers.

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

More details here:

http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers

I've reported the bug. Hopefully mainline Ubuntu 14.10 gets a driver update.

Comment: Include the bug link?